# Acronyms in Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, natbib, acronyms

Is it possible to add acronyms to a bibTeX file?

I have a bibTeX entry that looks like the following when printed with `natbib`:[image]

And when used within the text it looks like:
[image]

I would like it to show IBM [2011] and it could look the same in the references print or something like International Business Machines (IBM). etc...

My current entry looks like:

```
@webpage{International-Business-Machines:2011aa,
    Author = {{International Business Machines}},
    Month = {February},
    Title = {{Common Public License}},
    Url = {http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-cpl.html},
    Year = {2011}}
```

Comment: I don't have a solution for `natbib`. With `biblatex`, you may you use the `shortauthor` field -- see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11658/change-entries-in-the-bibliography-author-too-long) question.

Comment: That was helpful, howiever I am not sure how to achieve the style that I am using with `biblatex`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the following option that seems to work better for aliases.

SOURCE: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natnotes.pdf

> **2.6 Citation aliasing**

> Sometimes one wants to refer to a reference with a special designation, rather than by the authors, i.e. as Paper I, Paper II. Such aliases can be defined and used, textual and/or parenthetical with:

```
\defcitealias{jon90}{Paper~I}
\citetalias{jon90} ) Paper I
\citepalias{jon90} ) (Paper I)
```

> These citation commands function much like `\citet` and `\citep`: they may take multiple keys in the
> argument, may contain notes, and are marked as hyperlinks.

Applied to your example, you might set

```
\defcitealias{International-Business-Machines:2011aa}{IBM [2011]}`
```

and then cite the piece via `\citetalias{International-Business-Machines:2011aa}`. A suggestion: You may want to simplify the key of this entry.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A hint: By prefixing a row with `>`, one can put it into quotation. And, by indenting a line of text by four spaces, it is formatted like a line of code.

Answer (score 5):

With `natbib`, you can simply use:

```
\citeyearpar[see IBM][]{International-Business-Machines:2011aa}
```