# How to split the bibligraphy into two with different bibnames?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, subdividing

I'm using texclipse with MiKTeX 2.8.

For my thesis I need to split my list of references into two parts: literature and online sources. I've so far:

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{harvard}
\citationmode{abbr} 
\bibliographystyle{agsm}    
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}{URL: \url} 
...
\bibliography{../bibtex/Literatur}
\renewcommand\bibname{Online Quellenverzeichniss}
\bibliography{../bibtex/Online}
```

I assume my bib file entries are correct, no errors warnings, except it will not find the citation keys for the entries in Online.bib for  the citations in my article.

Though I will get the two chapters with different tiles, there are the same entries (of the first bib "Literatur") on both.

Is there a way to get this to work properly or do I have to go another way?

Comment: You may find more (and better) answers on tex.stackexchange.com. The moderators can move your question there, use the "flag" link for this (and leave a comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no experience with the `harvard` package and its `agsm` style, so I can only make some general remarks.

In "traditional" LaTeX, producing bibliographies subdived by reference type or topic is often done using the [`multibib`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/multibib.html) package. BibTeX (the program that is responsible for assembling the bibliographic data) must be run multiple times (each time on a different `.aux` file created by LaTeX) in order to produce multiple `.bbl` files (which serve as basis for the typeset bibliographies). This may not be possible automatically with texclipse and therefore cause the problem you observe.

If you are not obliged to use the harvard/agsm combo, I recommend to switch to the [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) package. Its author-year-styles are similar to the `agsm` style (and can be tweaked to your liking), and producing subdivided bibliographies is very easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works great in combination with keywords. Now I have just to adjust the style a little bit.

Comment: @Markus: For some details about adjusting biblatex styles see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6743/biblatex-changing-the-order-of-entries) question.

Comment: I messed up. :-( I can't even remember what I did wrong to get the warnings "Data encoding is 'utf8'" and "Empty bibliography on line ...". And, of course no bibliography entry or title in the output.

Comment: @Markus: There are a lot of compilable minimal examples for biblatex available at our site ([example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11658/change-entries-in-the-bibliography-author-too-long/11662#11662)). Try one and see if it works.

Comment: @lockstep no, but there is a different warning "LaTeX Warning: Citation 'long' on page 1 undefined on input line 21." And no list, of course.

Comment: @Markus: What happens if you delete all auxiliary files? (Sorry, I'm rather illiterate regarding editor problems.) If nothing works, consider to ask a new (follow-up) question with a link to this one.

Answer (score 5):

You could also consider using `biblatex` . With `biblatex` you could simply use:

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Literatuur},nottype=online]

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Online},type=online]
```

In case you are interested http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html

Comment: In your code example, please consider changing `type=book` to `nottype=online`. This way, everything but online resources would be covered by the first bibliography.

Comment: You are right, thx for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

[This FAQ answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-multbib) discusses a few possible approaches, using 4 different packages: `bibtopic`, `multibbl`, `multibib` and `splitbib`.

`multibbl` and `multibib` require you to use a different type of citation command for your literature vs online sources, which doesn't seem to be how you have things set up. `splitbib` requires you to explicitly list which bibliography you want each reference in.

`bibtopic` divides the bibliographies based on the .bib files, as you requested, so that is probably the correct choice for you. However, `bibtopic` is incompatible with `harvard`, so you will need to switch to `natbib` (which can do everything `harvard` can, and more).