# How to add more bibliographies with different names

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split the bibligraphy into two with different bibnames?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12116/how-to-split-the-bibligraphy-into-two-with-different-bibnames)

Hi,

I would like to add two separate bibliographies in my document but I also would like to give them different names - "References" and "Referenced blogs". How should I do that? Or - rather - what should I write to my code?

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{literatura1}
```

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12116/how-to-split-the-bibligraphy-into-two-with-different-bibnames) question -- and I really recommend biblatex.

Comment: I'd vote to close as a duplicate if I were not a moderator.

Comment: @Joseph Wright @lockstep @Nika: I've deleted my answer since this is, in fact, a duplicate.