# Bibliography with different names and ordered by name

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I would like to create two bibliographies with two different names. My two bibliographies are books.bib and articles.bib

Doing :

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{References from Books}
```

after `\begin{document}` and then introducing the bibliograpy with :

```
\nocite*
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{books} %
```

works for books.bib.

I would like to the do the same thing with articles.bib and the title "References from articles".

Moreover, I need items to be referenced in alphabetical order in both cases.

Comment: Does this link http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multbib or [How to split the bibligraphy into two with different bibnames?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12116/35864) help, you might also like a read of the [`multibib` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibib)? You can do this very easily with `biblatex`, you might want to have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, I've already had a look at multibib but it is way complicated.  I was looking after something easy. How would use biblatex regarding my example ?