# Reference Name Abbreviation

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm writing up my thesis in LaTeX, using the natbib package for my reference list. I was wondering if there was any way to abbreviate a reference name from the second in-text reference onwards?

i.e. the first in-text reference would be something like 
"(Community Agency for Social Enquiry (CASE), 2012)", and from thereafter, "(CASE, 2012)"

Thanks :)

Comment: You can do that easily with `biblatex`.

Comment: Related (almost duplicate question): [Natbib cite with abbreviation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87172)  I think your best plan would be to use this solution for the citations and just put in your first long form citation manually.  Depending on how far along you are in your thesis, switching to `biblatex` may not be an option for you.