# Configure acronym citation

Tags: bibtex, citing, acronyms

This question is related to the following [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87168/natbib-cite-with-abbreviation).

I would like to know if there exists a way to configure the command `\acroauthor` so that it's generate (Organization for the Advancement of Structured Information Standards, 2012) when it is used once and (OASIS, 2012) from the second time it is used?

Answer (score 1):

You have to slightly amend the macro `\acroauthor` to get that right:

```
    \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{oasis,
     author={{\acroauthor{Organization for the Advancement of Structured Information Standards}{OASIS}}},
     title={Some title},
     journal={J. Something},
     year={2012},
    }
    \end{filecontents*}
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    \newif\ifabbreviation
    \pretocmd{\thebibliography}{\global\abbreviationfalse}{}{}
    \AtBeginDocument{\global\abbreviationfalse}
    \DeclareRobustCommand\acroauthor[2]{%
      \ifabbreviation #2\else #1\global\abbreviationtrue\fi}

    \begin{document}

    Here it is \citep{oasis}

    A second time \citep{oasis}

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{\jobname}

    \end{document}
```

This will get the desired output.

[image]

Comment: How can I add the acronym (OASIS) after Organization for the Advancement of Structured Information Standards in the references? Without changing how the first quote is appearing, that is, [Organization for the Advancement of Structured Information Standards, 2012].

Comment: @VictorHugo you can use the `acro` package or the `acronym` package, define a suitable abbreviation with the package and use `author = {\ac{OASIS}}` (or similar) in the `bib` file