# Natbib citation, abbreviation, and aea.bst

Tags: natbib, acronyms

This is a follow-up question from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87168/natbib-cite-with-abbreviation/87172). One of the examples in the top solution work well with the `plainnat` style, but when I used the `aea` style, it threw an error.

Here is the `aea` style with a MWE that does not involve acronyms.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{oasis,
        author={{Organization for the Advancement of Structured Information Standards}},
        title={Some title},
        journal={J. Something},
        year={2012},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
    
Here it is \citep{oasis}
    
A second time \citep{oasis}
    
\bibliographystyle{aea}
\bibliography{\jobname}
    
\end{document}
```

The output is very good:

[image: regular author name]

However, with the acronym, TexStudio won't compile:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{oasis,
        author={{\acroauthor{Organization for the Advancement of Structured Information Standards}{OASIS}}},
        title={Some title},
        journal={J. Something},
        year={2012},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newif\ifabbreviation
\pretocmd{\thebibliography}{\abbreviationfalse}{}{}
\AtBeginDocument{\abbreviationtrue}
\DeclareRobustCommand\acroauthor[2]{%
    \ifabbreviation
    \ifcsname acroused@#2\endcsname
    #2%
    \else
    #1%
    %~(\mbox{#2})% <----
    \expandafter\gdef\csname acroused@#2\endcsname{}%
    \fi
    \else
    #1
    (\mbox{#2})%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
    
Here it is \citep{oasis}
    
A second time \citep{oasis}
    
\bibliographystyle{aea}
\bibliography{\jobname}
    
\end{document}
```

Instead, it throws three errors along with two warnings:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. ...nformation Standards}{OASIS}}}{2012}{oasis}
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. ...nformation Standards}{OASIS}}}{2012}{oasis}
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. ...nformation Standards}{OASIS}}}{2012}{oasis}
File `document.bib' already exists on the system.
Empty `thebibliography' environment
```

For reference, `aea.bst` can be obtained [here](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/policies/templates), in the zip file called `LaTeX templates`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package, you could use its citation aliasing machinery to create the desired citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{oasis,
   author={{Organization for the Advancement of Structured 
           Information Standards {(OASIS)}}},
   title={Some title},
   journal={J. Something},
   year={2012},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aea}
\defcitealias{oasis}{OASIS}
\newcommand\mycitep[1]{\citepalias[\citeyear{#1}]{#1}}
\newcommand\mycitet[1]{\citetalias{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}  

\begin{document}
\mycitep{oasis}, \mycitet{oasis}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I was aware of the existence of `\defcitealias`, but I had not thought to use a combination of `\defcitealias`, `\newcommand`, and `\citeyear`. This answer works well for me for my current needs.